# How to implement multi-select input with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Here are some exsamples:

[image: google plus]
[image: google plus] (from google plus)
[image: so-tags] (from stackoverflow)

How to implement multi-select input with jQuery?(Any of above is fine). Is there any jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the following libraries

1. Jquery Choosen.  [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)
2. Token Input [Token Input](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)
3. [Jquery Auto suggest](https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest/)
4. Jquery autocomplete [Auto complete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)
5. facebook Multi select [Fcebook Multiselect](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/jquerymultiselect.html)
6. [MagicSuggest Combo](http://nicolasbize.github.com/magicsuggest)

Answer (score 1):

I thing you are looking for something exactly like this

[FCBKcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/jquerymultiselect.html)

[see the Demo Here](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete/)